# Problems with analyzing comments in PRAW with python

Tags: python, parsing, comments

So, I'm making a small reddit bot that just scrapes for a term in comments, but I'm getting weird results. I'm very new to python, so this code might be a bit messy and amature-ish.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import praw

import pprint

user_agent = ("simple praw script for searching post terms in comments by /u/shadowfire452")
reddit = praw.Reddit(user_agent = user_agent)
reddit.login()
v_fixed = []
subreddit = reddit.get_subreddit('politics' and 'worldnews')

for submission in subreddit.get_hot(limit = 100):
    title = submission.title
    if " " in title.lower(): 
        v_fixed.append(title)
print "The following %d posts might not make much sense ..." % (len(v_fixed))
for fixed in v_fixed:
    print "\t%s" % (fixed)




flat_comment_generator = praw.helpers.flatten_tree(submission.comments)

for comment in flat_comment_generator:
    if "you" in comment.body:
        a = []
        commentz = comment.body
        a.append(commentz)
        print comment.body
        print ("I found %s comments with 'you' in it out of 100 posts") % (len(a))
    else:
           print "I found no comments with 'you' in it"
```

When I run it, I get:

```
I found 1 comments with ' ' in it out of 100 posts
I found no comments with ' ' in it
I found no comments with ' ' in it
I found no comments with ' ' in it
I found no comments with ' ' in it
```

Obviously this is an issue, since I'm getting conflicting answers and 5 replies to 1 request.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

```
import praw # simple interface to the reddit API, also handles rate limiting of requests
import re
from collections import deque 
from time import sleep

USERNAME  = ""
PASSWORD  = ""
USERAGENT = "bot/1.0 by USERNAME"

r = praw.Reddit(USERAGENT)
r.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD) # necessary if your bot will talk to people

cache = deque(maxlen = 200) # To make sure we don't duplicate effort

# Set of words to find in the comment body.
# I have changed this to a set.
words = set(["these", "are", "the", "words", "to", "find"])

def word_check(comment_body, words):
    # Will split the comment_body into individual words and check each for membership in words

    # Split comment into words
    comment_words = comment_body.split()

    # Check each word for hot word and return True if found
    for word in comment_words:
        if word in words:
            return True

    # Return false if no words in words
    return False

def bot_action(comment, reply):
    print "Body:", comment.body
    print "Found word in:", comment.subreddit.display_name
    comment.reply(reply)

# Loop through comments
running = True
while running:
    all = r.get_comments('politics', limit = None)
    for comment in all:
        # if comment id exists in cache, break
        if comment.id in cache:
            break
        cache.append(comment.id) # cache already found comment id
        # execute method for comment body and hotword(s)
        if word_check(comment.body, words):
            try:
                # action the bot to reply
                bot_action(comment, "Hello world")
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                running = False
            except praw.errors.APIException, e:
                print "[ERROR]:", e
                print "Sleeping for 30 seconds"
                sleep(30)
            except Exception, e: # In reality you don't want to just catch everything like this, but this is toy code.
                print "[ERROR]:", e
                print "Blindly handling error"
                continue
```